# spring application - get RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

file : CourseApiApp.java

```
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter;


        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class CourseApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //this is the first step to convert the application into spring app
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class,args);

    }
}
```

File HelloControllerTwo

```
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class HelloControllerTwo {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

I have created a very basic spring app to get hi on /hello path. I but I am still getting a fallback /error message on /hello

Could anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@RequestMapping` annotation should be on your **method**, not your **class**. 
You should also specify a method in your annotation.

Try this:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```